# PagerSlidingTabStrip Icon Change On select

Tags: android, icons, pagerslidingtabstrip

Can anyone help in displaying a dynamic Tab icon on the selection of the tab by using a PagerSlidingTabStrip?

I searched, but could not find any proper example for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
public void setTabBackground(int resId)
```

of that library inside

[onPageSelected (int position)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html#onPageSelected%28int%29)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But i need to change icon, not background of the Tab